# Python - Insert column based on condition check from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to insert a column with values 'True' and 'False' based on a validation using a separate column. The issue I'm having is that the condition is dependent on another column, acting as the dictionary (which uses regex) key.

E.g.

Table I have:

| Type | Value |
| --- | --- |
| TypeA | a1111 |
| TypeB | 1b111 |
| TypeC | 11c11 |
| TypeD | 111d1 |
| TypeD | 1111e |

Dictionary I have:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | \w\d\d\d\d |
| B | \d\w\d\d\d |
| C | \d\d\w\d\d |
| D | \d\d\d\w\d |

Result I want:

| Type | Value | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TypeA | a1111 | True |
| TypeB | 1b111 | True |
| TypeC | 11c11 | True |
| TypeD | 111d1 | True |
| TypeD | 1111e | False |

Any help would be appreciated!

I have tried playing around with numpy.where() but haven't had much luck.

Comment: Nested `np.where` should work. Possibly `mask` as well. `Map()` might work better. I'll try to put something together later. You can get going with nested 'np.where` so long https://medium.com/@AKayode_research/np-where-the-titanic-83bdc0a16b11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.vectorize` to create a lambda function that takes `Value` and pattern, and return `True` or `False` based on the output of `re.match`.

```
import re

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Type": ["TypeA", "TypeB", "TypeC", "TypeD", "TypeD"], 
    "Value": ["a1111", "1b111", "11c11", "111d1", "1111e"]
})

# Create the dictionary dataframe
df_dict = pd.DataFrame({
    "Column A": ["A", "B", "C", "D"], 
    "Column B": [r"\w\d\d\d\d", r"\d\w\d\d\d", r"\d\d\w\d\d", r"\d\d\d\w\d"]
})
# Add "Type" to the beginning of each value to match the "Type" column in the main dataframe
df_dict["Column A"] = "Type" + df_dict["Column A"]

# Merge the two dataframes to get corresponding regex pattern for "Type"
df = df.merge(df_dict, left_on="Type", right_on="Column A")

match_func = np.vectorize(lambda x, pattern: True if re.match(pattern, x) else False)  # Create a vectorized function to match the regex pattern
df["Result"] = match_func(df["Value"], df["Column B"])  # Add the result to the dataframe
df = df.drop(columns=["Column A", "Column B"])  # Drop the columns that are no longer needed
df

    Type  Value  Result
0  TypeA  a1111    True
1  TypeB  1b111    True
2  TypeC  11c11    True
3  TypeD  111d1    True
4  TypeD  1111e   False
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just One Line**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Type':'TypeA','TypeB','TypeC','TypeD','TypeD'],
                 'Value':['a1111','1b111','11c11','111d1','1111e']})
re_dict={'A':r'\w\d\d\d\d','B':r'\d\w\d\d\d','C':r'\d\d\w\d\d','D':r'\d\d\d\w\d'}

df['result']=df.apply(lambda row:re.match(re_dict[row['Type'][-1]],row['Value'])!=None,axis=1)


    Type    Value   result
0   TypeA   a1111   True
1   TypeB   1b111   True
2   TypeC   11c11   True
3   TypeD   111d1   True
4   TypeD   1111e   False
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Series.map` and `re.match` functions:

```
d = {'A':'\w\d\d\d\d','B':'\d\w\d\d\d','C':'\d\d\w\d\d','D':'\d\d\d\w\d'}
df['Result'] = df.Type.str[-1].map(d)
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda x: bool(re.match(x.Result, x.Value)), axis=1)
```

---

```
   Type  Value  Result
0  TypeA  a1111    True
1  TypeB  1b111    True
2  TypeC  11c11    True
3  TypeD  111d1    True
4  TypeD  1111e   False
```